# loss becomes 'nan' in all of epochs in Keras ANN (regression)

Tags: python, keras, nan

I have a regression problem and I've made a Keras ANN.

All of my data type (both feature and target matrix) are float;
I have 3 layers(5 input nodes, two hidden_layers with 3 nodes, and 1 output node);
optimizer='adam', batch_size='10', loss='mean_squared_error' and activation functions are 'relu' except the last one which is 'linear'.
due to training, all of my epochs losses are 'nan', and also my predicted values are all 'nan'!

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Miss Derakhshan data (1).csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:6].values 
y = dataset.iloc[:, 8].values 


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

regression = Sequential()

regression.add(Dense(units = 4, input_dim = 5,  kernel_initializer= 'uniform', 
activation = 'relu'))

regression.add(Dense(units = 3, kernel_initializer = 'uniform' , activation = 'relu'))

regression.add(Dense(units = 1 , kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'linear'))

regression.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

regression.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 5 , epochs = 100)
y_pred = regression.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `X` and `y` variables contain indeed indeed float values? Perhaps pandas is loading them as strings from the cvs. You could try to use `X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:6].values .astype(np.float)` (same for y) and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: thanks for your comment @massimo ; I did it but unfortunately nothing changed!